# Dispatcher didn't update label

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox which I put some files, if the file is not AVI I automatically converts it  but I want when the files converting message will write on a label that the files are now converted to another format, what happens to me now is only when the program has finished converting them its update the label and not in the process

after all the fixes:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnPlay.IsEnabled = false;
    Stream checkStream = null;
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    openFileDialog.Title = "Please Select Source File";

    if ((bool)openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        if ((checkStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            foreach (string file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
                    listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < listBoxFiles.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                string path = (string)listBoxFiles.Items[i];
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

                if (fileInfo.Extension != ".AVI")
                {
                    listToRemove.Add(path);
                }
            }

            (new System.Threading.Thread(ProcessAviFiles)).Start();

            foreach (string file in listToRemove) //remove all non .AVI files from listbox
            {
                listBoxFiles.Items.Remove(file);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }

    if (listBoxFiles.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        btnClear.IsEnabled = true;
        btnPlay.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    listToRemove.RemoveRange(0, listToRemove.Count);

}
```

function:

```
public void ProcessAviFiles()
{
    if (listToRemove.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    lblStatus2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { lblStatus2.Content = "Convert file to .AVI..."; }));

    foreach (String file in listToRemove)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        editpcap = new EditCap(fileInfo);
        String newFileName = editpcap._newFileName;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                listBoxFiles.Items.Add(editpcap._newFileName);
            }));
    }

    lblStatus2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
        () => 
    { 
        lblStatus2.Content = "Select adapter and packet file, Click play button to start.";
        btnClear.IsEnabled = true;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The label is not updating because the main UI thread is busy doing other things.

Looking to your code, it seems that you are running the AVI file conversion business inside your main UI thread. You should run this time consuming task in a separate thread to make sure your UI stays responsive.

Below is a fix to your problem, replace your `foreach (String file in listToRemove){}` by:

```
Action aviConversion = new Action(() => { 
    if(listToRemove.Count == 0) return; // nothing to do
    lblStatus2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                               new Action(() => { lblStatus2.Content = "Convert file to .AVI...";});
        );
     foreach (String file in listToRemove){
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        editpcap = new (classes who convert the files)(fileInfo);
        String newFileName = editpcap._newFileName;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                               new Action(() => { 
                               listBoxFiles.Items.Add(newFileName);
        }));
     }
     lblStatus2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                               new Action(() => { lblStatus2.Content = "AVI file conversion finished...";});
});
// Run this action in a separate thread...
Task.Factory.StartNew(action, "beta");
```

**EDIT** Using `Thread` instead of `Task` (OP can't use `Task`)

```
private void ProcessAviFiles(){
        if(listToRemove.Count == 0) return; // nothing to do
        lblStatus2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                   new Action(() => { lblStatus2.Content = "Convert file to .AVI...";});
            );
         foreach (String file in listToRemove){
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            editpcap = new (classes who convert the files)(fileInfo);
            String newFileName = editpcap._newFileName;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                               new Action(() => { 
                               listBoxFiles.Items.Add(newFileName);
            }));
         }
         lblStatus2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                   new Action(() => { lblStatus2.Content = "AVI file conversion finished...";});
}
```

replace your `foreach (String file in listToRemove){}` by:

```
(new System.Threading.Thread(ProcessAviFiles)).Start();
```

Comment: i cannot use Task because i am use .Net 3.5 and cannot upgrade to .Net 4 because its computers from my work and its not so easy.

Comment: now its OK but the program crash here: listBoxFiles.Items.Add(editpcap._newFileName); in the function ProcessAviFiles() with error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." that's was my problem from the beginning

Comment: @user979033 Sorry my bad. I forgot to enclose that one in a UI call as well. Please see my update.

Comment: Thank you very very much ! BTW, its possible during the convert process ("Convert file to .AVI...") to show soothing like circle progress or something ?

Comment: @user979033 Yes that is possible. Have a look at this article http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/ Please don't forget to accept this as anwser if it helped you :)

Comment: is it possible to use Dispatcher with WinForms ?

Comment: @user979033 I don't think so. Dispatcher is proper to WPF. You could easily achieve the same thing in WinForm using a delegate and a simple check for the calling thread.

Comment: i don't know how to do it, can you help me with this ?

Comment: @user979033 Sure no problem. Please submit another question regarding your new problem and post the link here. I would be more than happy to help. Please don't forget to mark this as a final answer to your question if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundWorker for the main task and dispatcher for UI updates.

```
 backgroundWorker1.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
 backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
 backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
 backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;          
 backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged +=new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
```